# How to prevent using production MongoDB URI in spock micronaut tests

Tags: mongodb, groovy, spock, micronaut, testcontainers

How can I ensure that my tests will never use the production MongoDB URI in my Micronaut application?

I am currently using an embedded server in my test configuration to run my tests with a test MongoDB container, like this:

```
@MicronautTest
class JwtAuthenticationSpec extends Specification {

final MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:6.0.3"))
        .withExposedPorts(27017)

def setup() {
    mongoDBContainer.start()
    embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer,
            ['mongodb.uri': "${mongoDBContainer.connectionString}/fire"]) //sets the uri to the test containers one
}
//...
```

And my MongoDB configuration in my application.yml is like this:

```
mongodb:
  uri: ${MONGO_PROD_URI}
```

My fear here is that a future developer could create a new test, using a new client without the embedded server, this would mean that the test would use the production url right? How can I avoid this to make sure that the tests will NEVER use the production url?

Comment: are your credentials to production hardcoded in the source code and those are overriden via test?

Comment: no, I have not a production yet, I'm just playing with micronaut =)

Currently, I have the credentials in an env variable, as you can see in the yml that I shared   uri: ${MONGO_PROD_URI}

My tests use an embedded server where I have replaced that uri config file to use the url coming from test containers. My fear is that someone with less knowledge, could do a test without knowing about this and not using the embedded server which means that the test would use the production credentials if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Micronaut Test Resources for MongoDB](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test-resources/latest/guide/#modules-mongodb).

See the Guide [Access a MongoDB Database with Micronaut Data MongoDB](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-mongodb-synchronous-gradle-java.html#test-resources)  demonstrating using MongoDB with Micronaut Test Resources and how to run in production:

> When the application is started locally — either under test or by
> running the application — resolution of the property mongodb.uri is
> detected and the Test Resources service will start a local MongoDB
> docker container, and inject the properties required to use this as
> the datasource.
>
> When running under production, you should replace this property with
> the location of your production MongoDB instance via an environment
> variable.
>
> `MONGODB_URI=mongodb://username:password@production-server:27017/databaseName`

**More Information**

The section on MongoDB in the Test Resource document is sparse. From the Introduction section:

> Test resources are only available during development (for example when running the Gradle `run` task or the Maven `mn:run` goal) and test execution: production code will require the resources to be available.

In a nutshell, Micronaut Test Resources handles spinning up your TestContainers for you.

Test Resources wouldn't stop a developer from setting the Production URI as an environment variable or the properties file.

You could do something like:

*/test/java/com/example/MongoContainer.java*

```java
@Factory
@Requires(env = Environment.TEST)
@Replaces(factory = DefaultMongoClientFactory.class)
public class MongoContainer {

    @Bean(preDestroy = "close")
    @Singleton
    @Primary
    public MongoClient create(MongoClientSettings settings) {
        MongoDBContainer container = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:6.0.3"))
                .withExposedPorts(27017);
        container.start();

        MongoClientSettings testClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder(settings).applyConnectionString(
                new ConnectionString(container.getConnectionString() + "/fire")).build();

        return MongoClients.create(testClientSettings);
    }
}
```

Which will ignore the `mongodb.uri` property all together for the test environment and your test cases wouldn't need to start the container. Note: could also add a property for the image name (`"mongo:6.0.3"`) in the factory above.

Comment: I don't really understand that doc tho, and it says to check the test resources doc for more info and there are literally 3 lines in it...
So if I understand the last part, I have to replace the mongo uri with a env variable which I have so the risk of using that property in a test exist. I am not sure what it means when it says that they inject things to make sure you use the container. Also, be aware that I am using test containers, not their test resources.

Comment: I updated the answer with more information.